# How to display username on page after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I have a MongoDB database populated with users, after they log in to the web page, I want to have a thing at the top that says Logged in as *username here*. I'm more comfortable with CSS while my javascript knowledge is lacking, therefore I can't seem to figure out how to get the login username displayed on the home screen.

My index javascript file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const hbs = require('hbs')
const collection = require('./mongodb')
const { link } = require('fs')

const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates')

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/stylesheets'))
app.use(express.json())
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', templatePath)
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login')
})

app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render('signup')
})


app.post('/signup', async(req, res) => {

  const data = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }

await collection.insertMany([data])

res.render('login')

})

app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {

try {
  const check = await collection.findOne({username: req.body.username})
  if(check.password === req.body.password) {
    res.render('home')
  }
  else {
    res.send('Wrong password')
  }
}
catch {
  res.send('Wrong sign-in credentials')
}

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('port is running, betta go catch it!')
})
```

the section on my home file where I'm trying to display the username:

```
   <div class="top-nav-left">
      <span class="logged-in-as">Logged in as: </span>
   </div>
```

Thank you.

I have tried using get and post requests to try to send the username data to my home file but have a very basic understanding of them and so it failed to work and I got nothing showing up on the home page. I then tried storing the data in a global variable but then again it displayed nothing on the home page.

Comment: it looks like you load an entire page on login, so add the username to the render context (you currently don't use a render context object) and have the HTML template include the code for that context variable.

Comment: Use a templating engine like express or pug, it would be easy for you to render objects on webpage by passing it like this res.render('login', { user: req.username })

Comment: Your server would need to know whether or not your user is logged-in. The typical way to provide it with such information is with a Session. See: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many method.

1st method: You have to manage session by using below code

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

set the username when user login sucessfully

```
req.session.username = req.body.username;
```

your home route will be like this:

```
app.get('/home',(req, res) => {
  res.render('home', {username: req.session.username});
})
```

in your home route,  access the session variable

```
app.get('/home',(req, res) => {
  res.render('home', {username: req.session.username});
})
```

in last home.hbs

```
<div class="top-nav-left">
   <span class="logged-in-as">Logged in as: {{username}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: does it matter where I put the home route? because I tried adding that code in different places but I couldnt get the username to show up still

Comment: or you can use a token base authorization. store the user id in token.when user login. and after that hit an another api to fetch current user data. where you will pass the auth token in header and follow these steps

1. Decode the token
2. get user id
3.send that in response